# Построить полигоны слева и справа от ломаной

Tags: c++, алгоритм, геометрия

У меня есть некоторая ломаная на плоскости, необходимо слева и справа от нее построить два многоугольника на заданных расстояниях.

Например:

Пусть задана красным цветом ломаная, относительно нее необходимо отстроить левый и правый полигон А и В. Таким образом, полигоны А и В как бы стыкуются в заданной ломаной. Для построения полигонов, с сохранением кривизны ломаной, задаются два расстояния, для левой и правой частей.

[image: полигоны слева и справа относительно ломаной]

Сложность заключается в том, что мне необходимо знать направление ломаной, чтобы двигаясь по этому направлению, на заданные расстояния от нее, получить необходимые точки конечных полигонов.

Ограничения исходных данных: 
1) Ломаная без самопересечений 
2) Ломаная не может быть загнута, т.е. например на одном значении оси X или Y лежит строго одна точка

Пишу на c++

Подкиньте идею)

Comment: А ломаная у вас как задается?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в виде набора точек 2D

Comment: Простейший вариант: возьите отрезок от начала до конца ломаной и постройте к нему перпендикуляр - это и будет вектор направления сдвига. Дальше каждую точку ломаной можно сдвинуть на этот вектор * расстояние и соединить концы.

Comment: @Lyth, вот я так изначально и подумала, но вот как этот сдвиг реализовать? Точнее как все это использовать?

Comment: Что Вы планируете делать с самопересекающимся результатом?

Comment: @Igor, я не понимаю вопроса. Откуда результат самопересекающийся, если ломаная без самопересечений?

Comment: @Naf Попробуйте нарисовать что-нибудь более сложное, чем плавненькая синусиода. Например, букву "П" со сходящимися ногами.

Comment: @Igor, самопересечений не будет у кривой

Comment: @Naf У буквы "П" тоже нет самопересечений. Я говорю не об исходной ломаной, а о получившейся после отступа.

Comment: @Naf Надо определиться: Вам нужен параллельный перенос всей ломаной (опасная штука - могут быть пересечения с исходной линией, неравномерные отступы от исходной, и куда, собственно надо переносить?), или равномерный отступ - не менее сложная задача, так как линия отступа не конгруэнтна исходной.

Comment: @Lyth Для тех, кто начинает свои комментарии словами "простейший вариант": https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00518005/document

Comment: @Igor Тогда нужно совсем другое решение :) То, что описано в вопросе, это не совсем то, что в статье - в последней решается много нюансов, возникающих при смещении. Там же решён и вопрос направления ломаной.

Comment: По-видимому речь идет о *монотонной* ломаной. То есть ломаная монотонна, напимер, вдоль прямой, прохродящей через ее концы. Это сильно упрощает задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, имеются точки C = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)] - это ломаная.

Отрезок (x1, y1) - (xn, yn) соединяет первую и последнюю точки. Сделаем из него вектор направления ломаной v:

(vx, vy) = (xn - x1, yn - y1)

И повернём на 90 градусов:

```
               | 0  -1 |
d = (vx, vy) * |       | =  (-vy, vx)
               | 1   0 |
```

Это вектор с абы какой длиной, повернутый перпендикулярно "направлению" ломаной. Тут будет куча нюансов, но о них позже. Пока нормализуем (приведём к длине 1):

```
vL = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)
dN = d / vL = (-vy / vL, vx / vL)
```

Собственно, теперь, имея расстояния, на которые надо отступить "слева" и "справа" (p, q), смешаем каждую точку и получаем новые ломаные:

```
 L= C + dN * p = [(x1 + dN.x * p, y1 + dN.y * p), ...]
 R= C - dN * q = [(x1 - dN.x * q, y1 - dN.y * q), ...]
```

Для замыкания их на оригинальную ломаную, добавить оригинальные точки в перевёрнутом порядке, иначе при отрисовке будут странные диагонали:

```
 M1 = [L1, L2, ..., Ln, Cn, Cn-1, ... C1]
 M2 = [R1, R2, ..., Rn, Cn, Cn-1, ... C1]
```

Теперь нюансы.

1. "Лево" и "право" очень относительные понятия, зависят от порядка точек в исходной ломаной. Если они заданы по проекции на плоскость, возможно, их придётся перевернуть.
2. Возможны ситуации, когда смещённая ломаная пересечётся с оригинальной, либо будет невозможно соединить прямыми начальные и конечные точки с оригинальной ломаной, чтобы получить непересекающийся полигон.

Пример второй ситуации:
[image: Сдвиг ломаной]

Красная при перемещении налезла на оригинальную; с зелёной не удаётся сделать полигон без пересечений.

Comment: Я дополнила вопрос ограничениями по исходным данным.

Comment: @Naf "Ломаная не может быть загнута, т.е. например на одном значении оси X или Y лежит строго одна точка" - это лучшее, что можно было ожидать, тогда проблем с полигонами не будет.